# Pragma to explicitly enable ARC?

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

Is there a `#pragma` (or otherwise some construct) to explicitly enable automatic reference counting (ARC) in an Objective-C (or Objective-C++) source file? Even better if the source file can cause compilation to fail if ARC is not enabled.

I'm starting to have a number of ARC-only source files that can be potentially shared with other projects.  Most of these contain category methods to extend built-in classes. I just don't want to accidentally include these in a non-ARC project and starts leaking out memory.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Nice question. Try to open a radar with Apple. Probably having a way to rise an error if the source code is not compiled in ARC mode would be of benefit for developers. As far as I know there are no arc-only statements that arise an error when compiled with -fno-obj-arc set.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As far as I can tell there is no way to explicitly enable or disable ARC.

However it is possible to detect if it is enabled. Simply add the following snippet to any file that requires ARC.

```
#ifndef __has_feature
  #define __has_feature(x) 0 /* for non-clang compilers */
#endif

#if !__has_feature(objc_arc)
  #error ARC must be enabled!
#endif
```

More info:
http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html
http://clang.llvm.org/docs/LanguageExtensions.html#__has_feature_extension