# How can I disable ARC in just part of a file, not the whole thing?

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Pragma to explicitly enable ARC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8136099/pragma-to-explicitly-enable-arc)

Basically, I want a part of a file to not use ARC, and the rest to use it (long story...). Aside from disabling ARC on a per-file basis, is there a way to do this with pre-compiler # commands?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. sorry.

It's been asked before one stack overflow before :

[Pragma to explicitly enable ARC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8136099/pragma-to-explicitly-enable-arc)

And by the developer community in general :

http://lists.cs.uiuc.edu/pipermail/llvmbugs/2012-March/022462.html

Answer (score 0):

You can only do this by adding `conditional blocks` one for ARC and other for without ARC..

First just define `ARC` as -

```
#ifndef __has_feature
// not LLVM Compiler
#define __has_feature(x) 0
#endif

#if __has_feature(objc_arc)
#define ARC
#endif
```

then you can user it like this -

```
#ifdef ARC
    //do your work with ARC 
#else
    //do your work without ARC
#endif
```

Comment: If you then use a link in the fileSystem with a slightly different name, you can then (possibly?) include the new file in the project, and set the per-file compile flags to turn ARC off. Wonder it that works?